# Laravel Does Not Sent Anything to Pusher

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

Pusher did not receive any data from my laravel project. in the debug console still waiting for events
and i didn't get any error message

`My Controller`

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $message = $user->messages()->create([
        'message' => $request->message,
        'room_id' => $request->room_id
    ]);

        broadcast(new MessageSent(auth()->user(), $message))->toOthers();

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Chat Has Been Added',
        ], 200);
}
```

`My Event`

```
public function __construct(User $user, GrupChat $grupchat)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->grupchat = $grupchat;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('chat');
}
```

}

And The `channels.php`

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
return Auth::check();
});
```

Comment: Have you set the correct broadcast driver?

Comment: yes . `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`